# Ad units is empty in AdInspector

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, admob

I am trying to integrate admob in my android application and I faced the problem that frequency capping is not working. After that I tried to add ad interspector to check what's going on, but for some reason Ad units are empty and I do not have any ideas what to do.

Here is how I added ad interspector in MainActivity (I use jetpack compose and hiltviewmodels)

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

        MobileAds.openAdInspector(this) {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured out the problem:

1. I had to set up device test id:

   val testDeviceIds = listOf("SOME_ID")
   val configuration =
   RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build()
   MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)
2. I had to fully reinstall the application. Not just rebuild it via Android Studio, but first delete from the phone and then install again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).